# Live field update in form in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access-2013

So I'm somewhat new to access 2013, anyways, I've created a form in access 2013 based directly off a table, so no queries involved if that matters, and what I'm trying to do is just have a text box that updates the total value of 3 different fields as they're entered.

right now it's just a plain-text box, the control source is "=[Search Cost]+[Update Cost]+[Copy Cost]", and if I close the form entirely and reopen the record it updates the text box with the total for all three, but the customer wants it to update in real time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your scenario in Access 2013 on a simple form and it updated for me in real time as I entered values. However, that was because each of the three fields values had a Default Value of 0 in my test table.

So I suspect this is not updating for you in real time because one or more of those values is null while you are entering data in the form. Access doesn't know what [Some field value]+Null should be (it's an unknown thing) so it won't display a calculated value in real time on your form until you provide a value for each of the three fields.

So how can you get around this?

1. You can add a Default Value of 0 or some other value to each of the three fields at the table level.
2. Or you could modify your form expression to use the NZ function which will convert any null values to zero. So use this expression:
   =Nz([Search Cost])+Nz([Update Cost])+Nz([Copy Cost])

Either of those options should achieve your end goal I believe. They did in my quick tests.

Comment: so I checked the default value of the three cost fields, in the table they were set to 0, and on the form there wasn't a value entered to I entered 0. didn't work, after that I attempted the expression in the control source that you put down, and it's still not updating live. Question, would the currency format interfere with this?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Well that is very strange indeed. It works perfectly fine in my local tests even if I use Currency fields and Currency formats. I tested on single forms, datasheet forms, and continuous forms. In all cases, the calculated field is being updated in real time as I enter data into the first three form controls. What form type are you using? I wonder if this could be a display refresh issue??? Can you tell me what Access build number you are using? You can find it by going to File > Account on the Backstage in Access 2013.

Comment: I'm out of the office at the moment, so I'll reply back with the access build in a bit, but I've had access freak out more than a few times while constructing this database, in one case actually disconnecting all the fields in a report from a query, that was fun. In anycase I'm using a single form format. I think what I'll do when I get back is make a new form just put in the 3 cost fields and a text box adding them up and see if it updates in real time. I'll let you know how that goes

Comment: Ok it's build 15.0.4701.1001, also now I'm completely convinced access freaked out and twisted up the form. I created a new form based off the same table, attempted the same things with just 5 fields (ID, Copy, Search, Update, and Total) and it updated in real time. so there's a display refresh issue with quite possibly most of my forms. if that's really the case then I'm going to be set a week behind.....no good, anyways, any further insight would be much appreciated

Comment: Update: Ok so if I build a form based off the primary table with ONLY the three monetary fields and the ID the total refreshes perfectly fine. If I recreate the entire form to include all the fields it will not update until i close the form entirely and reopen the records. This even happens if I have access generate all the fields based on the table and just add in the totals text-box. any ideas?

Comment: I think part of the problem is that access doesn't actually enter the data from the form into the table until you either open a new record, have it submit the record, or close the form. The way I cured this was by having access save the record to the table after they update the third cost on the list. Once that's done it populates the total. it's probably not very efficient but it works